# Make Jenkins Pipeline stage run conditionally by checking for a substring in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

> What syntax should be used in a `Jenkinsfile` to cause a stage to run conditionally based on whether the name of the branch being checked out **contains a specific substring**?

For example, if one stage might only run if the branch name contains the characters "bottom-level-branch".  That stage would then run for various branches, such as the following:

```
bottom-level-branch-1  
bottom-level-branch-2  
bottom-level-branch-3
```

And another stage would only run if the branch name contains the characters "middle-level-branch".  This other stage would then run for various other branches, such as the following:

```
middle-level-branch-1  
middle-level-branch-2  
middle-level-branch-3
```

The example below is too rigid because it does a strict match for string equality instead of checking for a substring:

```
    stage('Deploy Bottom Level Branch') {
        when {
            branch 'bottom-level-branch'
        }
        steps {
            sh './jenkins/scripts/some-script.sh'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy Middle Level Branch') {
        when {
            branch 'middle-level-branch'
        }
        steps {
            sh './jenkins/scripts/some-script.sh'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like (untried)

```
when { 
    expression { 
        return env.BRANCH_NAME.contains('bottom-level-branch') 
    }
}
```

[Syntax Definition](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default Pattern matching to specify the branch name. For the specific example that you mentioned, you can try something like this.

```
stage('Deploy Bottom Level Branch') {
    when {
        branch 'bottom-level-branch-*'
    }
    steps {
        sh './jenkins/scripts/some-script.sh'
    }
}
```

For more examples you can refer the documentation here : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @OliverCharlesworth, updated the answer.. It is not real regex, but more like pattern matching.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608104/whats-the-pattern-evaluation-on-jenkinsfile-when-branch-setting) it's an 'Ant style pattern'.  For regex, use an `expression` in the `when` instead.