# What's the pattern evaluation on Jenkinsfile when-branch setting?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am trying to detect the branch pattern on a when statement inside a stage.

Like this:

```
stage('deploy to staging') {
agent label:'some-node'
when { branch "feature/*" }
steps {
    sh './deploy_pr.sh'
}
```

}

What if I want a more complicated pattern?

I am trying to detect something like feature/0.10.25 and the following pattern doesn't work:

```
when { branch 'feature/[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+' }
```

Doesn't work . And it's a correct regexp, according to https://regexr.com/

Comment: You probable want to escape the period (`\.`). It should still match though.

Answer (score 13):

Ok ! So, through the error stack trace I found out that on the when-branch option, Jenkins compares with Ant style patterns:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html

That means it doesn't expect regexp, but simpler stuff like:

```
        */staging/*
```

I solved this by using the when-expression option instead, like this:

```
        when { 
            expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ /feature\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ }
        }
```

That uses groovy expressions as described here:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html

Especially, look for the explanation of the ==~ operator, that was helpful.

For the regular expression itself, you can test yours here:

https://regexr.com/

Comment: can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, i.e.: `BRANCH_NAME ==~ /feature\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+/`

Comment: Wanted to say that in this case, `BRANCH_NAME` directly corresponds to an environment variable that's set in your Jenkins pipeline. For me, `BRANCH_NAME` didn't exist, but `GIT_BRANCH` did.

Comment: @Mani I think it depends on you using multibranch pipeline (BRANCH_NAME), like I did, or a normal pipeline (GIT_BRANCH).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383273/get-git-branch-name-in-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0):

The `when` clause uses GLOB (Ant-style) patterns by default but can be switched to REGEXP with a parameter. So the initial question in this thread might have been solved by the following fragment:

```
when { branch pattern: 'feature/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+', comparator: 'REGEXP' }
```

See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Note that in Groovy/Jenkinsfile you often have to double-escape backslashes.

See https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4